# Azure function as a web role

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

I have a web role cloud service that generates a PDF file from an HTML file.
I have to use a web role as otherwise Azure does not let my process to have enough access for PDF generation. Now I want to migrate that service to an azure function. 
Is there a way to have an azure function with the same access level as a web role ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'access level'? Do you need access to more memory, or network ports, or processes, etc

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson I am using evopdf to generate a PDF file from HTML.
When you use a Web App Service Azure does not allow you to perform the conversion as PDF generation requires win32 api access.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Functions run in the same sandbox as a Web App, so no, you will not be able to install your PDF software there (same limitations).

You'd be able to migrate anything that doesn't require low-level installation, and leave your PDF generation within your web/worker role (or a VM).

Comment: Even if I'll host it inside a dedicated app service plan ?

Comment: Even if you try very very hard

Answer (score -1):

As [Azure Web App sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox) states as follows:

> The following PDF generators are supported:
>
> - <del>EVOPDF: See http://www.evopdf.com/azure-html-to-pdf-converter.aspx for vendor solution</del>
> - Rotativa / wkhtmltopdf: requires the site to run in Basic or higher.
> - NReco PdfGenerator (wkhtmltopdf): requires subscription plan Basic or higher

**Note:** Just make sure you are using the Basic or higher App Service Plan. Moreover, here is a tutorial about [Azure App Services - Using Azure App Services to Convert a Web Page to PDF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt707529.aspx), you could refer to it.

**UPDATE:**

For [EVOPDF](http://www.evopdf.com/azure-html-to-pdf-converter.aspx), the vendor developed a solution consisting in a service that you can deploy as a separate Azure Worker Role and a client library that you can link directly into your Azure Website to call that service completely transparent for you. **For directly using EVOPDF in Azure Web App, it is impossible.** Here is a similar issue, you could refer to [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47215259/hosting-winnovative-html-to-pdf-converter-in-azure/47219015#47219015).

Comment: Did you read the content of the links you posted? Evopdf ‘s page specifically states you can *not* use a web app. And the tutorial you linked to says the same.

Comment: It's my fault to list the EVOPDF as the option, I have updated my answer with the explanation.